# How to match a column name and find out the column position in awk?

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I am trying to parse some csv files using awk. I am new to shell scripting and awk.
The csv file i am working on looks something like this :

```
fnName,minAccessTime,maxAccessTime
getInfo,300,600
getStage,600,800
getStage,600,800
getInfo,250,620
getInfo,200,700
getStage,700,1000
getInfo,280,600
```

I need to find the average AccessTimes of the different functions.

I have been working with awk and have been able to get the average times provided the exact column numbers are specified like **$2, $3** etc.

However I need to have a general script in which if i input "minAccessTime" in the command argument, I need the script to print the average AccessTime (instead of explicitly specifying $2 or $3 while using awk).

I have been googling about this and saw in various forums but none of them seems to work.
Can someone tell me how to do this ? It would be of great help !

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `awk` script should give you all that you want.

It first evaluates which column you're interested in by using the name passed in as the `COLM` variable and checking against the first line. It converts this into an index (it's left as the default 0 if it couldn't find the column).

It then basically runs through all other lines in your input file. On all these other lines (assuming you've specified a valid column), it updates the count, sum, minimum and maximum for both the overall data plus each individual function name.

The former is stored in `count`, `sum`, `min` and `max`. The latter are stored in associative arrays with similar names (with `_arr` appended).

Then, once all records are read, the `END` section outputs the information.

```
NR == 1 {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if ($i == COLM) {
            cidx = i;
        }
    }
}

NR > 1 {
    if (cidx > 0) {
        count++;
        sum += $cidx;
        if (count == 1) {
            min = $cidx;
            max = $cidx;
        } else {
            if ($cidx < min) { min = $cidx; }
            if ($cidx > max) { max = $cidx; }
        }

        count_arr[$1]++;
        sum_arr[$1] += $cidx;
        if (count_arr[$1] == 1) {
            min_arr[$1] = $cidx;
            max_arr[$1] = $cidx;
        } else {
            if ($cidx < min_arr[$1]) { min_arr[$1] = $cidx; }
            if ($cidx > max_arr[$1]) { max_arr[$1] = $cidx; }
        }
    }
}

END {
    if (cidx == 0) {
        print "Column '" COLM "' does not exist"
    } else {
        print "Overall:"
        print "   Total records = " count
        print "   Sum of column = " sum
        if (count > 0) {
            print "   Min of column = " min
            print "   Max of column = " max
            print "   Avg of column = " sum / count
        }
        for (task in count_arr) {
            print "Function " task ":"
            print "   Total records = " count_arr[task]
            print "   Sum of column = " sum_arr[task]
            print "   Min of column = " min_arr[task]
            print "   Max of column = " max_arr[task]
            print "   Avg of column = " sum_arr[task] / count_arr[task]
        }
    }
}
```

Storing that script into `qq.awk` and placing your sample data into `qq.in`, then running:

```
awk -F, -vCOLM=minAccessTime -f qq.awk qq.in
```

generates the following output, which I'm relatively certain will give you every possible piece of information you need:

```
Overall:
   Total records = 7
   Sum of column = 2930
   Min of column = 200
   Max of column = 700
   Avg of column = 418.571
Function getStage:
   Total records = 3
   Sum of column = 1900
   Min of column = 600
   Max of column = 700
   Avg of column = 633.333
Function getInfo:
   Total records = 4
   Sum of column = 1030
   Min of column = 200
   Max of column = 300
   Avg of column = 257.5
```

For `maxAccessTime, you get:

```
Overall:
   Total records = 7
   Sum of column = 5120
   Min of column = 600
   Max of column = 1000
   Avg of column = 731.429
Function getStage:
   Total records = 3
   Sum of column = 2600
   Min of column = 800
   Max of column = 1000
   Avg of column = 866.667
Function getInfo:
   Total records = 4
   Sum of column = 2520
   Min of column = 600
   Max of column = 700
   Avg of column = 630
```

And, for `xyzzy` (a non-existent column), you'll see:

```
Column 'xyzzy' does not exist
```

Comment: @paxdiablo... Thank You very much.. Your solution provides much much more than what i asked.. Infact my next task was to find out the Maximum and Minimum of all the values.. Ur code will be very very helpful...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the requirements correctly, you want the average of a column, and you'd like to specify the column by name.

Try the following script (`avg.awk`):

```
BEGIN {
  FS=",";
}

NR == 1 {
  for (i=1; i <= NF; ++i) {
    if ($i == SELECTED_FIELD) {
      SELECTED_COL=i;
    }
  }
}

NR > 1 && $1 ~ SELECTED_FNAME {
  sum[$1] = sum[$1] + $SELECTED_COL;
  count[$1] = count[$1] + 1;
}

END {
  for (f in sum) {
    printf("Average %s for %s: %d\n", SELECTED_FIELD, f, sum[f] / count[f]);
  }
}
```

and invoke your script like this

```
awk -v SELECTED_FIELD=minAccessTime -f avg.awk < data.csv
```

or

```
awk -v SELECTED_FIELD=maxAccessTime -f avg.awk < data.csv
```

or

```
awk -v SELECTED_FIELD=maxAccessTime -v SELECTED_FNAME=getInfo -f avg.awk < data.csv
```

EDIT:

Rewritten to group by function name (assumed to be first field)

EDIT2:

Rewritten to allow additional parameter to filter by function name (assumed to be first field)

Comment: I've rewritten the awk script to group by function name, which I think is more what you were after.

Comment: @beny23.. yes.. this is exactly what i needed.. But this script provides the average times for each function in the csv file. However  want to also specify the function name to get the results...

Previously i did this by making use of pattern matching to select particular records for processing. But using the script u provided, I am not able to do the same. Can u pls provide an update to deal with this also ? Thanks..